# Retry failed jQuery.ajax requests

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I need to create a function that retries a failed ajax request until a given limit, *but* I need to ensure the promise is only rejected when the maximum of retries was exceeded, like this:

```
function my_ajax(...) { ... }

// then I use it this way
return $.when(my_ajax('foo.json'), my_ajax('bar.json'))
```

In order to work with jQuery.when, only one promise should be returned of `my_ajax`, which should be resolved when the internal jQuery.ajax is resolved, and rejected only when the maximum of retries was made.

The code I made is this:

```
function do_ajax(args, dfd, attempt) {
    dfd     || (dfd = $.Deferred());
    attempt || (attempt = 1);

    $.ajax(args).then(dfd.resolve, function(xhr, text_status, error_thrown) {
        console.error(/* something useful */);
        attempt++;

        if(attempt > 3) {
            dfd.reject(xhr, text_status, error_thrown);
        } else {
            do_ajax(args, dfd, attempt);
        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();
}

// in some random code
return $.when(do_ajax({url:'foo.json'}), do_ajax({url:'bar.json'});
```

This works for me*, but it's kind of hard to understand. The question is: is there a better (and easier to read) way to do it?

* - Actually I didn't tested to fail sometimes, but I works fine when the first ajax request is successful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to retry an AJAX request on failure using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024469/whats-the-best-way-to-retry-an-ajax-request-on-failure-using-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code is the right way to do it, wrap your call in a new Deferred and return it until all attempts are reached.

You could try to include your recursive call inside a anonymous function to improve readibility maybe.

I wrote it like that :

```
function doAjax(ajaxArgs, attempt) {
    // the wrapped returned dfd
    var wrappedDfd = $.Deferred();

    // your nested call using attempt counter
    (function nestedCall() {
        // if call succed, resolve the wrapped dfd
        $.ajax(ajaxArgs).then(wrappedDfd.resolve, function() {
            // update attempt counter
            attempt--;
            if (attempt > 0) {
                // try another call
                nestedCall();
            } else {
                // max try reached, reject wrapped dfd
                wrappedDfd.reject();
            }
        });
    })();

    return wrappedDfd.promise();
};
```

which is really similar to your code.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtG5p/). For test purpose, I replaced doAjax arguments by a mock factory call, but the code stay the same.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Mordhak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1206403/mordhak)'s answer and a few others around SO [dherman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/748746/dherman) has created a jQuery plugin: [jquery.ajaxRetry](http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxRetry/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/dcherman/jQuery.ajaxRetry)) and so has [johnkpaul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571435/johnkpaul) : [jquery.ajax-retry](https://github.com/johnkpaul/jquery-ajax-retry)

**jquery.ajaxRetry**

Example

```
$.ajax({
  // Retry this request up to 2 times
  shouldRetry: 2
});
```

- Can retry indefinitely
- Can retry `n` times
- Can run a function and evaluate to `true` or `false` in `shouldRetry` to determine if it should keep retrying

**jquery.ajax-retry**

Example

```
$.ajax(options).retry({times:3, timeout:3000}).then(function(){
    alert("success!");
  });
```

- Can retry `n` times
- Can specify amount of time to wait between retries
- Can specify what status codes to retry for