# EventListeners, onreadystatechange, or jQuery for AJAX calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-listener, onreadystatechange

I'm making calls to the **OpenWeatherMap API** to get a weather forecast JSON object. I used 3 different javascript methods that are called when someone enters a zipcode in the zipweather html id element and presses submit or enter, calling `zipWeather()` and basically pasting the zipcode to the end of the api address which then sends back the data on that zipcode.

They all work fine. They all get a city name and temperature that is converted into Fahrenheit.

They all use a callback in the error handler to the function itself in case of failure. The first one uses a 5 second timeout callback.

`onreadystatechange` method:

```
function zipWeather() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
//responseText code
}
// else ifs for readystate 3 2 and 1 gives a console log
else {
console.log("request failed, retrying in 5 seconds...");
window.setTimeout(zipWeather, 5000);
return;
}
}
xhr.open("GET", "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + document.getElementById("zipweather").value,
true);

xhr.send();
```

event listeners instead of `onreadystatechange`:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
//responseText code
}, false)

xhr.addEventListener("error", function(err) {
console.log(err);
if (weatherData.retryCount <= weatherData.retryMax) {
    weatherData.retryCount++;
    console.log(weatherData.retryCount);
    console.log(err);
    zipWeather();
    return;
    }
else {
return;
}
```

and of course jquery:

```
function zipWeather() {
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + $("#zipweather").val(),
data: {},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {
console.log(data.name);
$('#weather').html(data.name).css({'color': 'blue', 'text-shadow': '1px 0.5px lightblue'});
//change from kelvin
var localTempF = Math.round((data.main.temp - 273.15) * 9/5 + 32);
$('#localtemp').html(localTempF + weatherData.localUnits);
weatherData.localTemperatureValue = localTempF;
},
timeout: 3000,
retryCount: 0,
retryMax: 5,
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
this.retryCount++;
    if (this.retryCount <= this.retryMax) {
    //try again
    $.ajax(this);
    return;
    }
return;
}
```

The last two methods use a `retryCount` and `retryMax` variable trick I found in [What's the best way to retry an AJAX request on failure using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024469/whats-the-best-way-to-retry-an-ajax-request-on-failure-using-jquery) so it doesn't keep calling the API if its down.

Finally, questions:

1. Are all of these methods virtually identical in terms of performance? Is there a potential catastrophic bug lurking in any method as written?
2. Is it most proper to use a callback in the error handler to the same function when using AJAX?
3. Are javascript code standards moving away from using `onreadystatechange` or event handlers and towards jquery `$.ajax` and `$.get` functions?

Thanks everyone. Sorry it was so long!

Comment: Since performance of ajax requests are highly dependant on the network speed, the performance of the javascript execution that causes the ajax request and then dispatches the handler (whether it be an event handler or a callback) is not important.

Comment: @kevin that's like saying:  "the minute-long trip to the airport is not important since the air time will be hours.  Yes the first affects the total.  Plus the question is not interested in network, but client side performance.

Comment: I guess the question I was trying to get at was: which is the best to use? Although it seems like it doesn't matter much except stylistically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably answer the performance question yourself with performance testing tools. I prefer event listeners because the code reads more cleanly. Bug-wise, I would categorize the lack of a way for the first method to break out of a callback loop if the service is down as a serious bug. It could cause performance degradation if the service is down, that is something to check with performance testing.

I don't know whether there is a convention to re-call the method in the error handler, but it seems like an OK way to handle it as long as you have a loop breakout. If the retry max is reached, you might want to alert the user and prompt them that the service call will be attempted again after some arbitrary period. See the way Gmail handles connection interruptions for an example of this behavior.

As for jQuery v. not jQuery, it depends on your use case. In a lightweight web page where you are performing minimal JavaScript coding, you might find jQuery to be overkill in terms of the size of the library. On the other hand, jQuery is popular because it papers over browser incompatibilities, letting you, the coder, focus on application functionality. If you load it from a popular CDN, many users may already have it in cache, so load time would not be a factor. As for what people use, jQuery is popular, but beyond that I don't know whether any statistics exist that break down the relative popularity of either method.

Comment: I checkmarked this response for the extra information. I'm kind of new to javascript and jquery, and stackoverflow for that matter, so appreciate all the help and encouragement. Is there a specific testing tool you would recommend in this case?

Comment: You can see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code on performance testing JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Answers to your three questions:

### 1. Performance

Since the way to send the request in JavaScript doesn't affect the actual network loading performance at all, it simply doesn't matter. Also, there's almost no client side performance difference between the three.

---

### 2. Callback when failing

You handle that actually very nicely and elegant. Don't worry about a method unless its slow or doesn't work :D

---

### 3. Which one?

That's totally up to you! If you want to do jQuery, do it. If you feel like doing plain JavaScript with event listeners, do that.

---

Hope it helps, if you have any questions, feel free to ask :)

Comment: Thanks, I probably should've rephrased the 3rd question as "which method do javascript developers use to do ajax?" since all 3 seem interchangeable I guess im to assume its at the discretion of the programmer?

Comment: @jarisky Edited accordingly.