# Retry failed ajax request in vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

What's the best way to retry failed AJAX request in VueJS ?

```
bulkDecline(requests, decliner) {
  requests = _.map(requests, 'id');
  return Vue.http.post(`${baseUrl}/api/decline/${decliner}/bulk-decline`, requests)
    .then(
      (response) => {
        Notification({
          title: 'Success!',
          message: response.data.message,
          type: 'success'
        });
        return response;
      }, 
      (response) => {
        this.bulkDecline(requests, decliner);
      }
    );
}
```

But it seems like its not working.

Comment: You can take inspiration from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10024557/1610034).

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this within a single-file component?

If so, have you tried using

```
this.$http.post
```

instead of `Vue.http.post`?

You may also have some luck if you send through your `requests` in an object like `{ data: requests }` or similar.

```
return this.$http.post(`${baseUrl}/api/decline/${decliner}/bulk-decline`, { data: requests })
```