# ajaxForm resubmit if needed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using `ajaxForm` to send data to php file which runs in background, and  some js functions will be checking if php file is running asynchroniously. So in case of some failure(internet/electricity went off), I want my user be able to retry the last form submission. So I found some ajax retry functions as this, [best way to retry ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024469/whats-the-best-way-to-retry-an-ajax-request-on-failure-using-jquery) but it is on the same ajax request, i need to be able to retry my ajax from another function. Is it even possible? Given that I am storing passed values in form.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#form').ajaxForm({
    target: '#ajax-response',
    success: function(){
 initAjaxCheck();
     }
});
Check();
});
```

So, basically lockcheck() checks if process is still runing after page refresh/reload, and if any failure was detected with prevous run, it should be able to retry the form submission.

Here's js scripts:

```js
function Check(){
    $.ajax({
 type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{'flag':'Check'},
        success:function(result){
         if (result=="1") {
      initAjaxCheck();
         } 
        }
    });
}



function initAjaxCheck(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajax.php",
        data:{'flag':'initProcCheck'},
        success:function(data){
         if (data=="1"){ 
  timerCheck=setInterval(function(){
      ajaxCheck(timerCheck);
  },1000);
            } else { //unsuccessful
            var toRepeat = confirm ("Last try was unsuccessful. Retry?");
            if (toRepeat){alert("retry");} else {alert("cancel");}
            }
        } 
    });
}
```

So if my user press RETRY, I should have to retry my ajaxForm submission.

Comment: i think you can just call `initAjaxCheck()` everytime user press retry. Javascript function can call itself inside the function. this is called recursive function.

Comment: @JacobGoh will it pass my form values to async php? `initAjaxCheck` is just a function to check process, if state of `ajaxForm` is `success`.

Comment: sorry, i dun really understand your function. I dun know how your data flows either. but you can put the data inside a variable and check if the data exists before every ajax call. If the data is not there on resubmit, just use something like `$('#my_input_field').val()` to grab the form value 1 by 1 and pass the value into the ajax call. hope this helps.

Comment: @JacobGoh thanx! i'd help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused with what exactly you are asking, however I believe I somewhat understand.

*Trigger a form submission.*

```
$('#form').trigger("submit");
```

or

```
var event = jQuery.Event("submit");
$('#form').trigger(event);
```

To implement this in your code, simply add it after your `confirm` function.

```
var toRepeat = confirm ("Last try was unsuccessful. Retry?");

if (toRepeat){
    alert("retry");
    $('#form').trigger("submit");
} else {
    alert("cancel");
}
```