# jQuery ajaxSetup, cannot retry ajax call into error handling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In `$.ajaxSetup()` I am trying to make an AJAX request after reloading a valid token if the previous token is expired. The problem is I cannot do `$.ajax(this)` inside the `error` callback.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: _url
  //async: false,
  type: 'POST'
}).success(function(jsonP) {
  // ...
}).error(
  // ...
);

$.ajaxSetup({
  tryCount: 0,
  retryLimit: 2,
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (xhr.status == 401 && (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Auth')).user[0] != null)) {
      refreshToken();
      this.tryCount++;
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(xhr);
        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) { // this.tryCount is undefined
          //try again
          $.ajax(this); // the problem is here : how to call the request again !
          $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
          return;
        } else {
          alert("Problème de connexion");
          return false;
        }
      }, 1000);
      return;
    } else {
      /* alert("Problème d'authentification");
      $(".logout").trigger('click'); */
    }
    if (xhr.status == 500) {
      //handle error
    } else {
      //handle error
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki have you idea about this ?

Comment: Check my answer bellow @ghazi

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Also per the docs it is suggested not to use `$.ajaxSetup`

Comment: Some good looking solutions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39812370/1175966

Comment: @charlietfl I am using jQuery v1.11.1

Comment: Ok. One of the solutions in that link above was rewritten to fix 3.0 bug but may still work. Several other decent solutions there though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put your request inside a function then call it inside the callback again like :

```
function myRequest(){
    $.ajax({
      url: _url
      //async: false,
      type: 'POST'
    }).success(function(jsonP) {
      // ...
    }).error(
      // ...
    );
}

myRequest();

$.ajaxSetup({
  tryCount: 0,
  retryLimit: 2,
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (xhr.status == 401 && (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Auth')).user[0] != null)) {
      refreshToken();
      this.tryCount++;
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(xhr);
        if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) { // this.tryCount is undefined
          //try again
          myRequest();

          $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
          return;
        } else {
          alert("Problème de connexion");
          return false;
        }
      }, 1000);
      return;
    } else {
      /* alert("Problème d'authentification");
      $(".logout").trigger('click'); */
    }
    if (xhr.status == 500) {
      //handle error
    } else {
      //handle error
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but if I want to do the same thing for all requests !

Comment: Docs for $.ajaxSetup clearly state it's not recommended to use it

Comment: now it's working but look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53535380/retrying-ajax-request-ignores-the-success-callback