# Retrying AJAX request ignores the success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to refresh an AJAX call if the token is expired. Everything works fine by using `ajaxSetup` but the request ignores the `success` callback.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: _url
  //async: false,
  type: 'POST'
}).success(function(jsonP) {
  console.log(jsonP);
}).error(
  // ...
);

$.ajaxSetup({
  tryCount: 0,
  retryLimit: 2,
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (xhr.status == 401 && (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Auth')).user[0] != null)) {
      refreshToken();
      var request = this;
      request.tryCount++;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (request.tryCount <= request.retryLimit) {
          //try again
          $.ajax(request);
          $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
        } else {
          alert("Problème de connexion");
        }
      }, 1000);
      return;
    } else {
      /* alert("Problème d'authentification");
      $(".logout").trigger('click'); */
    }
    if (xhr.status == 500) {
      //handle error
    } else {
      //handle error
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their was an error in $.ajax(); syntax. When I ran that code it says success is not a function. So I corrected that too below $.ajax syntax:

JS Code:

**Method 1**: Reference Link: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.co.in/abc.php", // _url, for time being replaced _url with another url
    //async: false,
    type: 'POST'
}).done(function(jsonP) {
    console.log("jsonP=", jsonP);
}).fail(function() {
    // ...
    console.log("Error Occurred");
});
```

**OR**

**Method 2**: Old style of using success & error functions in $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.google.co.in/abc.php", // _url, for time being replaced _url with another url
    //async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    /*error: function() {
        console.log("Error occurred");
    },*/
    success: function(jsonP) {
        console.log("jsonP=", jsonP);
    }
});
```

Also one more note, if $.ajax() request contains it's own "error" handler function then it ignores the error function written in $.ajaxSetup method.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    tryCount: 0,
    retryLimit: 2,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            refreshToken();
            var request = this;
            request.tryCount++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (request.tryCount <= request.retryLimit) {
                    //try again
                    $.ajax(request);
                    $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    alert("Problème de connexion");
                }
            }, 1000);
            return;
        } else {
            // commented existing code for testing purpose only
            /* alert("Problème d'authentification");
            $(".logout").trigger('click'); */

            // for time being I had added here refresh ajax code to verify whether it's working fine or not
            var request = this;
            request.tryCount++;
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (request.tryCount <= request.retryLimit) {
                    //try again
                    $.ajax(request);
                    // $('#loading-modal').modal('hide');
                } else {
                    alert("Problème de connexion");
                }
            }, 1000);
            return;
        }
        if (xhr.status == 500) {
            //handle error
        } else {
            //handle error
        }
    }
});
```

Related to "success" callback ignoring, for making it sure it's working or not. I have  just changed console.log 
**FROM**: console.log(jsonP);

**TO**: console.log("jsonP=", jsonP);

And that success callback is working. I guess it wasn't been working due to erroneous ajax syntax.

Comment: it's not working !! the `$.ajax(request)` works fine but the problem is only success even I changed the console log to this `console.log("--------- success");`

Comment: did you changed the URL: **FROM**: "https://www.google.co.in/abc.php", **TO**: your own valid url which generates a proper response?

Comment: yes I changed it, if I put the ajax call request in a function , and call this function inside ajaxSetup it will work but with `$.ajax(request)` will ignore `success` !!

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for the same?

Comment: sorry I can't create that, can we collaborate in jsfiddle ?

Comment: Currently $.ajaxsetup handles error AJAX requests, inside that error functions it retries AJAX request 2 which is as per retry limit set. Their are very rare conditions where 1st AJAX request to particular URL get's failed and then after same AJAX request get's triggered from error handling function written in $.ajaxsetup. For testing purpose, whether success handler works or not when using $.ajax(request). I have created a fiddle where, I have written a common code for success handler in fiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/yvqc2o0d/6/". Please replace url in $.ajax to your valid page URL.

Comment: You will get to see that, success handler written in $.ajaxsetup works continuously until "retrylimit" is reached. Just copy the JS code from fiddle and try it in your own development environment.

Comment: thnak you @Prasard for your help, but what about each request has a specific  usage inside sucess function and I want to retry only that function with their usage !

Comment: I mean just ajaxSetup will intercept all request ajax if 401 error and recall it

Comment: Didn't get you, what you suppose to say?. Success function will be called when you are using $ajax(request) too. And that we have verified with $.ajaxsetup. Related to ajax with 401 only recall the AJAX request. For testing purpose only. I had put up else block with recalling of AJAX request. I had mentioned the same in code comments too.

Comment: all my thanks my friend its' working now, the problem is about `$.ajax().success()` I changed it to `$.ajax(url:_url , type: _tye , success : { // here } )`